# Using Statement take a long time, timed out sometimes

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am new to ASP.NET. I guess I don't know when to use the USING statement.  when I try it in my code, example below. It takes forever and timed out sometimes. When I run without using, it works fine.

Can someone please to clarify the USING statement? when should I use it and when I should not.

This code is taking forever, and timed out.
    ... Some codes up here. Open DB Connection Execute....

```
cmdinsert.CommandText = insertcommand;
cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

Using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Import_EvaluationMatch", connSQL, trans))
    {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@RefNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RefNum;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
trans.Commit();
connSQL.Close();

Response.Write("Import Successfully");
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
Response.End();
```

Removed the USING statement, it works fine.

```
... Some codes up here. Open DB Connection Execute....
cmdinsert.CommandText = insertcommand;
cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();


// --- Now calling the stored procedure to process all this imported items.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Import_EvaluationMatch", connSQL, trans);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@RefNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RefNum;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit();
connSQL.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement is not taking any time. What's taking time is the cleanup of your `SqlCommand`. When you use a `using` statement, the cleanup happens in-line. When you don't use it, then the cleanup happens at random, whenever the garbage collector decides.

It's a case of "pay me now, or pay me later".

What's wrong is that your `Import_EvaluationMatch` stored procedure is taking too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Huh, I run the Import_EvaluationMatch and it is really fast. So the clean up is really taking that long?

Comment: Apparently, yes. Maybe this has something to do with your use of transactions. Try not using transactions and see how fast it is (only as a toubleshooting technique).